# Is it possible to declare a global variable so that it can be used from every class in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, global-variables

I'm developing a little web application with JSP, this application requires a database connection, which i provide with a servlet.

The problem is, i would like that all the files on the server can use this class to access the db without creating each time a new connection, in fact in every file i would create a new `Database` object and a new connection would be established each time.

Is there a way to avoid this, maybe declaring a global object such as `session` and `request`, so that it will be initialized only one time and then used by all my JSP files?

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend to research the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), and DB connection pooling... Also, dealing with DB connections at JSP level is something I'd try and avoid at all costs. JSP should only be for display, IMHO.

Comment: maybe a database connection pool would be appropriate?

Comment: singleton object for DB connection would be a better idea , create the object in the context of your application

Comment: Both of the folks who are recommending singletons are dead wrong.  Ignore both comments.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid So, if i declare a static `Connection` object to my database, and then i access it through a `synchronized` method, i will be using a single connection to handle all queries?

Comment: @duffymo Why is it wrong to use singletons? Do you also recommend using DB Connection Pooling?

Comment: i dont think you 're gonna need any synchronization , but only create the singleton object for DB connection

Comment: refer this link , and check out the answer by @jon Skeet "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339059/is-static-method-in-java-creates-a-single-instance/15339103#15339103"

Comment: Here's what Google thinks of singletons: http://code.google.com/p/google-singleton-detector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want to do this?  Both solutions are the wrong way to go.

It's a bad idea because database connections are not thread safe.  Creating a global object will degrade the throughput of your app, because every user will have to share the connection.

A better solution is to have a connection pool, maintained by the app server.  Do a JNDI lookup to check a connection out of the pool, use it in the narrowest scope possible, and close the connection in that method scope.

Your app will scale better and won't risk thread safety.

Comment: What library do you suggest me to use? I saw DBPool, do you suggest to use some other library?

Comment: Apache Commons Database Connection Pool is in common use: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp//

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a global variable, you need a functionality for your context, that will be used by your application. So you need to use JNDI, in Tomcat web page you have a how to do it, it is well explained and easy to implement. Best regards.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be talking about using directly a database connection from your JSP files, don't you? Well, this is not a theoretically correct solution because following separation of concerns principle, your view -your JSP file- shouldn't know anything at all about databases or data access. Check any description of MVC pattern, for instance this pretty obvious ;-):

[Wikipedia on MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

But if you want to take the shorcut and have your view aware of your database you have, in my opinion, two options, both of them involving the JNDI lookup of a datasource previously defined in your appplication as [Marcelo Tataje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1193148/marcelo-tataje) already said.

On how to define on Tomcat a JNDI datasource based on a connection pool:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

In the same page you can see how to use this connection pool to issue queries right from your JSP (again very inadvisable in my opinion)

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<sql:query var="rs" dataSource="jdbc/TestDB">
select id, foo, bar from testdata
</sql:query>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>DB Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h2>Results</h2>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${rs.rows}">
    Foo ${row.foo}<br/>
    Bar ${row.bar}<br/>
</c:forEach>

  </body>
</html>
```

[Is java.sql.Connection thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531073/is-java-sql-connection-thread-safe)

The other slightly better solution is, in your java code, JNDI lookup the datasource like this from your context listener:

```
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
        // JNDI Datasource lookup   
        InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context
                .lookup("jdbc/DataSource");
        // Storing datasource in application context
        contextEvent.getServletContext().setAttribute("datasource",dataSource);
   }
```

and after from any servlet use that stored datasource to get the database connection you need like this

```
((DataSource)contextEvent.getServletContext().getAttribute("datasource")).getConnection()
```

Don't use Connection class directly please. It's awfully primitive and obsolete. Nowadays nobody in a serious working environment handle connections like that. If you do what [AmitG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115584/amitg) proposed you will end up with an unique connection shared by all concurrent accesses. See this on why this isn't the way to go

Comment: I didn't talk about accessing db directly with JSP, i use a servlet to connect and do all queries